# Equivalent 2D mask of moving-average

Tags: image-processing, lowpass-filter, moving-average

I have the moving-average mask as

```
   mask = [1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1];
```

and then I compute the convolution 3 times

```
   imageF = conv2(conv2(conv2(originalImage, mask), mask), mask);
```

I want to know how can I get an equivalent mask to compute the filter with just one convolution

```
   imageF = conv2(originalImage, equivMask);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convolution in linear time-invariant system is asociative. So to get the equivalent mask you just need to convolve the kernel with itself twice. This will then then give you a 7x7 kernel:

```
octave:1> a = [ 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 ; 1 1 1 ]
a =

   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1

octave:2> conv2(a,conv2(a,a))
ans =

    1    3    6    7    6    3    1
    3    9   18   21   18    9    3
    6   18   36   42   36   18    6
    7   21   42   49   42   21    7
    6   18   36   42   36   18    6
    3    9   18   21   18    9    3
    1    3    6    7    6    3    1

octave:3>
```

Note that the original mask is not normalised - it has a gain of 9 at DC - so with three convolutions you get an overall gain of 9^3.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve though you might just be better off with a 7x7 Gaussian.

Comment: No, in fact what I meant was conv(conv(conv2(OriginalImage, mask), mask), mask).

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought you meant, and this is then equivalent to using the 7x7 kernel above.

Comment: Good answer. I think you should add a sentence about the fact that it is possible due to the fact that convolution is associative.

Comment: Really? I'm really impressed, I mean, I didn't know and didn't think that. How can I verify it? On what properties can I see that?

Comment: Should this resulting kernel be normalized?

Comment: Thanks for the above comments on associativity and normalisation - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @BRabbit27: an easy way to verify this is to consider an image with a single white pixel, i.e. a unit impulse. If you convolve this with your average mask three times in succession this will give you the equivalent 7x7 mask as above.

Comment: Is there a way to get the equivalent mask for N times of convolutions? I mean for three times the convolution it gives the 7x7 mask, how to know the mask after 20 convolutions...

Comment: You can just repeatedly convolve with the original mask. Obviously the kernel will grow by 2 in each dimension for each iteration so after 20 convolutions the kernel will be 41x41.